# How to make a web browser on iphone automatically add the http://www. before any URL

Tags: http, url, web

I was making a web browser for iphone and I wanted to know how make the web browser automatically add the `http:// www` before any URL the user puts.

Comment: "1)When the user confirms the URL 2) if it doesn't start with `http://www.`, 3) add `http://www.` to it". What more do you expect from us? Of course, you should handle the cases where it starts with `http://` only or `www.` only as well (and allow `https://` and other protocols ...)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us any code or even specify your language, so I assume you're asking for the correct algorithm that you already know where to add:

If you want to add `http://www.` to any URL, you certainly can, but that is hardly recommendable. One would, for example, think `http://www.en.wikipedia.org` didn't work. I believe you can find a page where it does break. `http://www.https://bank.example.com` is definitely invalid.

I recommend this:

1. if the URL doesn't start with a protocol specified (regex for "protocol specified": `^\w+\:\/\/`), prepend `http://`
2. try to DNS-lookup or access the URL.
3. if the lookup fails, and the URL doesn't already start with `www.`, prepend `www.`.
4. you can stop here. You have already handled the prefix as well as you can.
5. if you added `www.`, make a new lookup
6. if the lookup still fails, try appending a popular top level domain (`.com`, `.net`, `.org`, ...) to the URL, both with and without `www.`.

You could even observe the user's habits to find which top level domains the user accesses the most, and try to append them first.

Of course, if you want something better, you can. Observe the behavior of the address bars in any modern desktop browser: It basically performs a fulltext search on the set of addresses ever accessed, weighted by the number (and freshness?) of accesses. You could even track the number of accesses vs. the string to access it, and not offer the URL for unrelated inputs. Chrome does track input vs. URL => hit count (how often the suggestion was successful) and miss count (how often the suggestion was unsuccessful).

Most likely, you'll need to make your own virtual keyboard for this, but this is but a small amount of work compared to writing a rendering core or javascript engine (or even a reasonably fast CSS engine).

Comment: I am actually making the web browser on xcode and i want it to have multiple windows like when there is a pop up it comes up.

Comment: I am actually making the web browser on xcode and i want it to have multiple windows like when there is a pop up it comes up.

Comment: How does that invalidate my answer? You still haven't posted enough code to let us fix it or extend it.

Comment: @synthesize webView;

-(IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[searchBar text]]]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
    
}

Comment: @AnuragMahlawat if you post this into the question (properly formatted), you may get more answers. Of course, you should have done it right ahead.

Comment: @AnuragMahlawat click the `edit` link below the question.